# How to prevent an textfield losing focus using jQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a textfield `<input type="text"/>` that I want to validate when the focus is lost. If the input is not valid, I want to prevent the focus moving to the next element, or in other words keep the focus at the invalid input until it's valid.

How can I do that using jQuery and JavaScript?

I have tried with this code, but it doesn't work ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdT8M/1/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.hello').bind('focusout', function(e) {
        if(!isValid($(this).val())) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).foucus();
        }
    });
});

    function isValid(str) {
        if(str === "hello") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Only valid content: <b>hello</b><br>
<input type="text" class="hello"/>
<button>Dummy</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your visitors will love this feature `:P` Especially the scenario when they accidentally click the input and then have to figure out how to validate that thing in order to get their caret back...

Comment: @Sime: Yes, it will improve the usability of my app. The field will be valid by default.

Comment: This is a good example of jQuery making things more complicated than they need to be.  Case in point, using native JavaScript the desired behavior can be implemented with less than half as much code:  http://jsfiddle.net/qdT8M/2/

Comment: @aroth Using `onevent` attributes and global functions is not a good alternative. Binding event handlers is without doubt a job for a library like jQuery, the reason for this being IE8 which doesn't implement W3C's Event API.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Whether or not it's a good alternative depends entirely upon context.  Binding event handlers dynamically is indeed a job for a framework, but that doesn't mean it is the best solution in this specific instance.  If the framework version requires more than twice as much code, then there should be a reason for using it that is more compelling than "`on*` attributes and global functions are bad".  They can be bad in certain contexts, while in others it really makes no difference.

Comment: @aroth Using `on*` event binding has some limited applications, but we do not know the context in this case. It's not proper to propose a `on*` solution without first investigating if the solution would be appropriate for the given context. Also, while you can defend `on*` binding (depending on the context), you cannot defend global functions. Polluting the global namespace is a bad practice in all contexts.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Fair enough about the global functions.  Though of course, those can be easily worked around in the native solution with something like `window.myNamespace = {};` and then doing `myNamespace.validate = ...;`, which still gives code that is significantly shorter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a typo. Change:

```
$(this).foucus();
```

To:

```
$(this).focus();
```

Also, you might want to make it easier for your users to correct their mistake by also calling `select` on the textbox. That way, they can just begin typing again to change the value:

```
$(this).focus().select();
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eu2Yc/).

---

*Note: This answer fixes the problem at hand, i.e. the question that was asked. On a broader scale, I do agree with the others who are saying that one shouldn't lock the user into a field. A better way of doing this would be to validate the whole form on submit, letting the users see all the problems and fixing them all at once, instead of bugging them throughout.*

Comment: I can't agree about whole form validation, which often loses data on the post back that you already typed (especially passwords). But why not just per field validation with NO field "lock in"?

Comment: I can see what you're saying, and per field validation is acceptable from a UX perspective if it doesn't lock you into the field. What I prefer personally, however, is to perform client-side validation on the whole form just prior to the submit action. (Of course, you would also do server-side validation.) I'm not an expert though, so maybe your way is actually better?

Answer (score 4):

The event should be `blur` you're looking for. And your original jsfiddle had a typo (.foucus instead of focus)

And as a commenter said, visitors won't like this behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/qdT8M/4/

Comment: Thanks, but the visitors will like it since it improves the usability.

Comment: @Jonas I'm going to respectfully disagree. You're locking your users into a field until they put in 100% valid input. Maybe they aren't ready to fill in that field, maybe they aren't sure what to put in that field, etc. If you're going to lock them into that field you better be very very clear about exactly what is needed. Users are dumb.

Comment: All fields will be valid by default, and there is no point leaving a field in an invalid state. It's better to let the user know that it is invalid and directly let the user correct it.

Comment: No, it's really not better. It's annoying. Validate the field, yes, but do it at the end, on submission of the form, so the user can deal with the issues all at once. Look around the web. This is the way other good websites do it, and for good reason.

Comment: While I agree it is not ideal to prevent the user from leaving a field sometimes it's unavoidable due to requirements (by a boss for example). Also to Dooser's point "users are stupid." Leaving something invalid is going to confuse them (it works both ways). To FishBasket's point my interface is an ajax one. You leave a field and it saves immediately via ajax. If it's invalid it needs to be caught immediately. Would love an alternative to keeping the user in the field but then data may be lost and that is much worse than a usability bug. An empty field is valid so there is the escape.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#input").focus();


$("#input").blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#input").focus(); }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(this).focus()`, use `$(this).trigger('focus');`. And the event should be `blur`, not `focusout`.

Edit: oh well, `focus()` will work as well :)